# Json comparison with different link among objects in python

Tags: python, json, compare

I'm trying to compare 2 json that show a different order in the ids value, even thouh they are concettually the same, as you can see from the example.

For instance, each person object points to an Address object based on its id. The ids could be different but, concettually, the 2 json are the same. Here an example: The order of the address_id is different (as the address object position), but the 2 json are the same, (John lives in NYC and Pippo in BCN).

```
{
   "Persons": [
     {
       "Name": "John",
       "Address_Id": "0"
     },
     {
       "Name": "Pippo",
       "Address_Id": "1"
     }
   ],
   "Addresses": [
     {
       "City": "NYC"
     },
     {
       "City": "BCN"
     }
   ]
 }


{
   "Persons": [
     {
       "Name": "John",
       "Address_Id": "1"
     },
     {
       "Name": "Pippo",
       "Address_Id": "0"
     }
   ],
   "Addresses": [
     {
       "City": "BCN"
     },
     {
       "City": "NYC"
     }
   ]
 }
```

Is there a way to compare the 2 json considering this "special case" ??

Thanks.

Comment: You can compare by the `Address_Id` but your question is not clear. What is your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialise the json yourself by creating the equivalent Python classes and implementing the comparison yourself
. For example:

```
import json

class Person_book:

    def __init__(self, person_list):
        self.person_list = person_list

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if len(self.person_list) != len(other.person_list):
            return False
        for person in self.person_list:
            if person not in other.person_list:
                return False
        return True

class Person:

    def __init__(self, person_id, address):
        self.person_id = person_id
        self.address = address

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.person_id) + ' ' + str(self.address )

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.person_id == other.person_id and self.address == other.address:
            return True
        return False

def deserialize_persons(persons_array):
    persons = persons_array['Persons']
    addresses = persons_array['Addresses']
    person_list = []
    for person in persons:
        person_entry = Person(person['Name'], addresses[int(person['Address_Id'])])
        person_list.append(person_entry)
    return Person_book(person_list)

json_resp_1 = """{
   "Persons": [
     {
       "Name": "John",
       "Address_Id": "0"
     },
     {
       "Name": "Pippo",
       "Address_Id": "1"
     }
   ],
   "Addresses": [
     {
       "City": "NYC"
     },
     {
       "City": "BCN"
     }
   ]
 }"""

json_resp_2 = """
{
   "Persons": [
     {
       "Name": "John",
       "Address_Id": "1"
     },
     {
       "Name": "Pippo",
       "Address_Id": "0"
     }
   ],
   "Addresses": [
     {
       "City": "BCN"
     },
     {
       "City": "NYC"
     }
   ]
 }"""

resp_1 = json.loads(json_resp_1)
resp_2 = json.loads(json_resp_2)

person_book_1 = deserialize_persons(resp_1)
person_book_2 = deserialize_persons(resp_2)

print(person_book_1 == person_book_2)
```